# How can I plot and curve fit multiple data sets within one data frame? in R

Tags: r, regression, curve-fitting, modeling, best-fit-curve

I have this df

```
   tree sdepth shallow_avg ddepth deep_avg swdepth sw_avg
  <dbl>  <dbl>       <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1     3      2      0.0857    3.5  0.0454      3.7      0
2     4      2      0.142     3.5  0.0991      4.1      0
3     5      2      0.0119    3.5  0.00498     5.7      0
4     7      2      0.0217    3.5  0.0169      5.1      0
```

I am trying to plot and curve fit each sarate tree. the (x,y) points are (0,0), (sdepth,shallow_avg), (ddepth,deep_average), and (swdepth,sw_avg)

my base code is

```
sample_data <- data.frame(x = c(0, 2, 3.5, 4.7), y = c(0, 0.0679, 0.0367, 0))

# fit polynomial regression models up to degree 5
linear_model5 <- lm(y~poly(x,5,raw=TRUE), data=sample_data)

# create a basic scatterplot 
plot(sample_data$x, sample_data$y)

# define x-axis values
x_axis <- seq(1, 10, length=10)

# add curve of each model to plot

lines(x_axis, predict(linear_model5, data.frame(x=x_axis)), col='orange')
```

but that is only doing one tree and is by hand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of problems generally has to do with reshaping the data. The format should be the long format and the data is in wide format. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) on how to reshape the data from wide to long format.

Reformat the data with the `x` columns and the `y` columns side by side. `bind_rows` will include the origin on each group of `tree`. Then `ggplot` will automatically separate the points and the lines by the color aesthetic.

It doesn't make sense to fit polynomials of the 5th degree to 4 data points so I have fitted polynomials of the 3rd degree, this can be changed by changing the value of `polydeg`.

```r
sample_data <- read.table(text = "
tree sdepth shallow_avg ddepth deep_avg swdepth sw_avg
1     3      2      0.0857    3.5  0.0454      3.7      0
2     4      2      0.142     3.5  0.0991      4.1      0
3     5      2      0.0119    3.5  0.00498     5.7      0
4     7      2      0.0217    3.5  0.0169      5.1      0", header = TRUE)

suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
  library(ggplot2)
})

polydeg <- 3L

df1 <- bind_cols(
  sample_data %>%
    select(-3, -5, -7) %>%
    pivot_longer(
      cols = -tree,
      names_to = "xcol",
      values_to = "x"
    ),
  sample_data %>%
    select(-2, -4, -6) %>%
    pivot_longer(
      cols = -tree,
      names_to = "ycol",
      values_to = "y"
    ) %>%
    select(-tree)
) %>%
  select(-xcol, -ycol) %>%
  mutate(tree = factor(tree))

bind_rows(
  df1 %>%
    group_by(tree) %>%
    summarise(tree = first(tree), x = 0, y = 0),
  df1
) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, color = tree)) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  geom_smooth(
    formula = y ~ poly(x, polydeg, raw = TRUE),
    method = lm,
    se = FALSE
  ) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: its impossible for y <0, how should i approach to add this to change the line fit on tree 3?

Comment: @DCB Try `method = loess` with `formula = y ~ x`.